# Chosen field in active_admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have model `User`. One field in this model is `gender`. This field is integer. If user choose male I set 1, and if user chose female - I save this field as 0.

Also I have another models with the same problem in admin interface. For example in one of them I save day of week. It's very bad create some table with rows which will not change in future, but I doesn't have better solution

How I can make this better in active admin?

Comment: How about two radio buttons?

Comment: Good idea! But this field isn't one that I need modify in admin interface. Maybe for this field I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get easy solution

```
column "Gender" do |user|
  link_to (user.gender == 1) ? "Male" : "Female", "javascript:void(0)"
end
```